# Which word for "maintenance" do I use in "the maintenance of the Quality (of a service)"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I looked up the many translations of "maintenance" and found quite a bit of entries. Among them that I found on Langenscheidt are:

- die Instandhaltung (for buildings)
- die Wartung (for machines)
- der Unterhalt (for food and accommodation)
- die Aufrechterhaltung and das Beibehalten (maintenance in the sense of retaining or preserving something)
- die Wahrung (for law and order)
- die Betreuung (maintenance in the sense of "care")
- die Behauptung and die Verfechtung (maintenance in the sense of maintaining one's POV)

I'm having trouble which translation would go in the context of "the maintenance of the quality (of a service)". Which translation suits best for this sentence?

Comment: The English original doesn't read like a native speaker has written it. A good translation would need more context. It could be a strange way to say "Qualitätssicherung" in English. It could be that "Aufrechterhaltung der Qualität" fits.

Comment: @Roland - The English is a bit awkward, but English speakers are capable of writing awkward phrases. A random result from Google: "The monitoring of the optical fiber infrastructure, especially within the interoffice range, is an essential procedure for the maintenance of the quality of service." DeepL does indeed render this with "Aufrechterhaltung". It is a bit odd to randomly capitalize "quality" though.

Comment: @RDBury Umm, your quote was written by someone from Portugal, who is probably not a native speaker of English.

Comment: @Roland - That's what I figured. It wasn't meant to be an example of a native English speaker using it, just a possible context since the question needs more. As a native English speaker myself, to me the sentence still seems awkward but not necessarily ESL. I haven't read the rest of the paper, and don't plan to, but it could very well use phrasing in other places that would sound odd to an native English speaker. Of course it's a technical paper so the whole thing is probably written in jargonese.

Answer (score 3):

You already stated the meanings of the different translations in your question.

So what remains is the question which of them fits, which depends on how you understand the meaning of the original.

I would understand "the maintenance of the quality (of a service)" to mean measures that make sure that the quality of the service is upheld/retained ("maintained").

In that sense, "Aufrechterhaltung" or maybe "Wahrung" would be good translations. They both mean that the quality is already good at the beginning and this good quality has to be retained.

Depending on context, "Betreuung" could also be fitting, in the sense of, as you wrote, continuous care.

More context would be needed to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

- Sicherstellung der Qualität.
- Gewährleistung der Qualität.